# Two floating divs over an image

Tags: html, css

Alright so I got 1 div that is float left and one with float right, now for some reason I cannot make them go to the side where they should be. They are kinda now both overlapping eachother

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main  {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#page_left, #page_right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <img src="img/background.jpg"/>
  <div id="page_left"></div>
  <div id="page_right"></div>
</div>
```

I also tried using a method with display inline block but it didnt work out so well

Comment: not sure what you asking,can you show an image of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with your additional css

CSS

```
#page_left, #page_right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#page_left {
    left: 0;
}

#page_right {
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I didnt know you could just do it like that, interesting! Thanks mate that worked out!

Comment: Basically you added ```position: absolute``` and also ```left: 0``` which were overriding your ```float``` style. You can use either ```float``` or ```position``` with ```left``` and ```right``` style.

Answer (score 0):

```
#page_left, #page_right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

remove `left: 0px`

OR

remove `position: absolute`

```
#page_left, #page_right {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the overflow in happened because you given **left:0px** and **position:absolute** for both the divs,I'm solved this and and added the snippet below.

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

html, body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#main  {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

#main img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

#page_left, #page_right {
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 1000;
}
#page_left{
  left: 0px;
}
#page_right{
  background-color:green;
  float:right;
  position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
  
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>



<html>

 <head>
 </head>
 
 
 <body>
  <div id="main">
   <img src="img/background.jpg"/>
   <div id="page_left">
    
   </div>
   
   <div id="page_right">
   
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```